# Avoid Babel dependencies at runtime

Tags: node.js, babeljs, transpiler

I am using Babel 6 to transpile my ES2015 project.

Packages used in `devDependencies`:

```
"babel-core": "*",
"babel-loader": "*",
"babel-preset-es2015": "*"
```

`.babelrc` contents:

```
{ "presets": ["es2015"] }
```

After transpiling and attempting to run, I get:

```
Error: Cannot find mode 'babel-runtime/core-js/json/stringify'
```

I *don't want to depend on `babel-runtime` in my project*. I simply want to transpile everything behind the scenes and publish pure ES5 for the user. I don't want to be weighed down by live Babel dependencies on the user end.

How can I get this to work without `babel-runtime`?

Comment: Are you passing any options to `babel-loader`? You generally wouldn't see `babel-runtime` in your code unless you specifically enabled `transform-runtime`.

Comment: No, funny enough, I'm not.

Comment: I'm not sure what to say. Babel doesn't do this by default. If you can make a reproducible example, that'd help a lot.

Comment: I am having this problem. Using RequireJS, RequireJS gives an error saying that stringify.js is looking for babel-runtime/core-js/json/stringify.js

Comment: E.g., I have this in my server logs: GET /babel-runtime/core-js/json/stringify.js 404 1.505 ms - 1291

Comment: I frankly am so confused why the front-end is trying to find this dependency. The front-end should not need babel-runtime at all, since it's all ES5 in the browser...right?

Comment: @loganfsmyth ok, so duh, my front end code was explicitly requiring this dependency! in the react code, we have: var _stringify = require('babel-runtime/core-js/json/stringify'); So how can I load that dependency into the front-end using requirejs? I think this is all because I tried my hand at server-side rendering.

Comment: It looks like what Babel is doing is replacing JSON.stringify with require('babel-runtime/core-js/json/stringify');....I am never explicitly invoking that dependency, Babel adds it to my code.